# Dictionary getting cut off

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

I don't know how much of the context is important but here it is. I am using Visual studio code.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

#(my_list) is full of random letters organized like this

my_list=
[
[IUVHVIUBVYIGU,KHVFUYKJBVIK],
[BAIDGIANDFAOIG,NJABOGIPASG],
[POIUJHJHUIOKJHY,NOAUVOUAIG]
]



#(ALL) is Series with that contains strings 
#like this
#0   'This is a string'
#1   'this is another string'


All=pd.Series()



#List of all capital letters in the Alphabet

Alphabet=list(map(chr, range(65, 91)))



#creates a Dictonary with letters of the Alphabet as keys
#and set the values to lists with all words in (ALL)
#that start with that letter
#ex.{'A':['Able','Andy'],'B:['Boy',Bounce]}

starts_with={letter:All[[val.startswith(letter) for val in All]].tolist() for letter in Alphabet}



#this looks at ever letter in every string in (my_list)
#and creates a dictionary with the string as the key (ex.IUVHVIUBVYIGU)
#and the values are a list of all strings from (ALL) that 
#contain the same first letter 
#ex. IUVHVIUBVYIGU{I:['Idego','Indecent'],U:['Unreal,'Under']}

c={string:[starts_with[letter] for letter in string] for pair in my_list for string in pair}
display(c)
```

***Problem: When I print (c) it doesn't go through all of the letters in (my_list) and even gets cut off at the end like this***

{TTTTTTTT[['this is a string','this is a string','this is a st

the actual out put is much longer than this

the parenthesis, brackets and braces never close either.

I have tried using display and sys.stdout.write but they give the same results

Did my program just give up and not finish or did my program finish and my Visual studio refuses to display it or is there a problem with my code?

I don't really need it to print I just need to know if my code is working and if possible what causes this.

Comment: this isn't functioning code (e.g. missing quotes around strings).  you may want to use a custom print routing that puts in newlines, like `for k,v in c.items(): print(c); print(len(v) + " items " + v[0:3])`

Answer (score 1):

*Did my program just give up and not finish*? Most probably it was the case as the code you provided in your question is not a valid Python code.

Try following code to see that it works as expected:

```
# I don't know how much of the context is important but here it is. I am using Visual studio code.
# Here is my code:
#(my_list) is full of random letters organized like this
my_list=[
'IUVHVIUBVYIGUKHVFUYKJBVIK',
'BAIDGIANDFAOIGNJABOGIPASG',
'POIUJHJHUIOKJHYNOAUVOUAIG'
]
#(ALL) is Series with that contains strings 
import pandas as pd
All=pd.Series(my_list)

#List of all capital letters in the Alphabet
Alphabet=list(map(chr, range(65, 91)))

#creates a Dictonary with letters of the Alphabet as keys
#and set the values to lists with all words in (ALL)
#that start with that letter
#ex.{'A':['Able','Andy'],'B:['Boy',Bounce]]}

starts_with={letter:All[[val.startswith(letter) for val in All]].tolist() for letter in Alphabet}

#this looks at ever letter in every string in (my_list)
#and creates a dictionary with the string as the key (ex.IUVHVIUBVYIGU)
#and the values are a list of all strings from (ALL) that 
#contain the same first letter 
#ex. IUVHVIUBVYIGU{I:['Idego','Indecent'],U:{'Unreal,'Under'}}

c={string:[starts_with[letter] for letter in string] for pair in my_list for string in pair}
print(c)
"""
Problem: When I print (c) it doesn't go through all of the letters in 
(my_list) and even gets cut off at the end like this

{TTTTTTTT[['this is a string','this is a string','this is a st

the actual out put is much longer than this
"""
```

The code above prints:

```
{'I': [['IUVHVIUBVYIGUKHVFUYKJBVIK']], 'U': [[]], 'V': [[]], 'H': [[]], 'B': [['BAIDGIANDFAOIGNJABOGIPASG']], 'Y': [[]], 'G': [[]], 'K': [[]], 'F': [[]], 'J': [[]], 'A': [[]], 'D': [[]], 'N': [[]], 'O': [[]], 'P': [['POIUJHJHUIOKJHYNOAUVOUAIG']], 'S': [[]]}
```

By the way:

```
# Use --v
import string
Alphabet=list(string.ascii_uppercase)
# instead of --v
Alphabet=list(map(chr, range(65, 91)))
```

If you change the code as I suggest it would be much better readable as you can see what will be stored in Alphabet, where in your code you must guess it from numbers. And as mentioned in one of the comments you can use in your code also directly:

```
Alphabet=string.ascii_uppercase
```

as a Python string behaves in for-loops like a list does providing as elements its single characters.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make it clear "All=pd.Series()" Should not contain (my_list) it is just there to represent a pandas series whose values are all strings(any set of words from English dictionary should work but they have to start with a capital letter)

Comment: What is the current state of your progress? As you know how code which runs ok looks like you should be able to find what is/was your issue? Maybe it was something wrong with "All" so the code gave up?

Comment: `[c for c in string.ascii_uppercase]` is an unnecessarily verbose way of writing `list(string.ascii_uppercase)` although in this case you don't need to use a list at all and the string `string.ascii_uppercase` would work fine by itself

Comment: Good point, thanks. Have updated my answer with it.